# Does $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1$ imply $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x+1)-f(x)}{g(x+1)-g(x)} = 1$ for convex functions?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convex-analysis, divergent-series

Let $f,g$ be convex functions on $[0,\infty)$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1$ and $\lim_{x\to +\infty} g(x) = +\infty$.

> Is it always true that $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x+1)-f(x)}{g(x+1)-g(x)} = 1$?

I can prove it when $g(x)=x$ and $g(x) = x^2$.

**Edit.** It is actually not so hard to show it works more generally when $g(x) = x^\alpha$ for any $\alpha \geq 1$.

The question can also be asked with series as a partial converse to the Stolz-Cesaro Theorem:

> Let $a$ and $b$ be *increasing* sequences such that and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n b_k = +\infty$.
>
> Does $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k}{\sum_{k=1}^n b_k} = 1$ imply $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{a_n}{b_n} = 1$?

Comment: If, for example, $g(x+1)/g(x)$ tends to a finite limit $a \neq 1$, then the statement is true. Since $g(x)$ tends to infinity and is convex, it is monotonic from a point $x^*$. Thus $$
\frac{f(x + 1) - f(x)}{g(x + 1) - g(x)} = \frac{\frac{f(x + 1)}{g(x + 1)} - \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\frac{g(x)}{g(x + 1)}}{1 - \frac{g(x)}{g(x + 1)}} \to \frac{1 - a}{1 - a} = 1.
$$
Note that the fraction on the left is well-defined for $x>x^*$.

Comment: That is a good point, but I'm actually mostly interested by $g(x) = x^\alpha$, in which case $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{g(x+1)}{g(x)} = 1$.

Comment: I have an idea but not sure whether it will work or not. We are fixing $g(x)=x^{\alpha}, \alpha\in \mathbb{N}.$ First prove it when $f$ is a polynomial (this can be done using the mean value theorem). Next, try to approximate $f$ uniformly by a sequence of polynomials $\{P_n\}$. Since uniform convergence gives $\|f/P_n -1\|_\infty \to 0,$ I think it could be done.

Comment: @Rhubarbe could you elaborate on how you proved the $g(x)=x^\alpha$ case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so.

Counter example for the $a_k$, $b_k$ case:
$$
a_k = 2^{\lfloor \log_2(k) \rfloor}  \quad\quad \text{and} \quad\quad b_k = 2^{\lfloor \log_2(k+1) \rfloor}
$$

So $a_k$ and $b_k$ are the same in most cases, except when $k=2^n-1$, we have $a_k=2^{(n-1)}, b_k=2^n$.

So apparently $a_{k+1}\geq a_k$, $b_{k+1}\geq b_k$, and $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{a_k}{b_k}$ does not exist

On the other hand, it can be shown that
$$
b_k\geq a_k\geq k/2\text{, So }\sum_{k=1}^N b_k \geq \sum_{k=1}^N a_k = \mathcal{O}(N^2)
$$
$$
\sum_{k=1}^N b_k - \sum_{k=1}^N a_k \leq N+\frac{N}{2} + \frac{N}{4} + .... \approx 2N
$$

Thus
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^N b_k - \sum_{k=1}^N a_k}{\sum_{k=1}^N b_k} = \lim_{N\to\infty}\mathcal{O}(\frac{N}{N^2}) = 0
$$

In summary, in this example, $a_k$ and $b_k$ are increasing sequences with $\sum_{k=1}^N a_k = + \infty$, and $\sum_{k=1}^N b_k = + \infty$,

We also have 
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^N a_k}{\sum_{k=1}^N b_k} =1
$$

but $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{a_k}{b_k}$ does not exist.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this is not a counter example since $f(x+1)-f(x) \sim 2^x \sim g(x+1)-g(x)$.

Comment: As noticed by Gary, a counter example must satisfy $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x+1)/g(x) = 1$.

Comment: @Rhubarbe, thank you for pointing my error. I think I got a better example this time.

Comment: Much better! I did not think such a neat counterexample would exist.